# Facebook webhook - retrieve page incoming message & send message through server

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm just get to try Facebook webhook very recently. 
I found out that Facebook seem already revoke page_messaging permission? 
The Facebook app still under development status, but need to provide app review already, it is correct procedure? That review required video & photo proof, I can't show video or even photo because don't have any single function done yet.

My question is

(1) just send & receive message, need "read_page_mailboxes" and "manage_pages" only right?

(2) How do I get through App review? Now in development can't test it due to no permission enable...

[image]

If I try to enable pages_messaging, below show up:

[image]

Comment: Appreciate someone point me out to correct direction for send & receive message permission. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=facebook+access+temporarily+disabled